# Notice: Undefined index: post_id

Tags: php

Hey on my blog I want to create the title of the blog posts and have it click-able to a new page with just that post on it. When I try it though I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: post_id in C:\wamp\www\blog_test\index.php on line 264 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0009322712{main}( )..\index.php:0 ">Fanboy-ism

here is line 264:

```
<h3><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $row_getDisplay['post_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['title']; ?></a></h3>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it, it is confusing me. Please && Thanks

EDIT:

The code for the server behaviours is as follows:

```
$maxRows_getArchives = 10;
$pageNum_getArchives = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getArchives'])) {
  $pageNum_getArchives = $_GET['pageNum_getArchives'];
}
$startRow_getArchives = $pageNum_getArchives * $maxRows_getArchives;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getArchives = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %Y') AS archive, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%Y-%m') AS link FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC";
$query_limit_getArchives = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getArchives, $startRow_getArchives, $maxRows_getArchives);
$getArchives = mysql_query($query_limit_getArchives, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getArchives = mysql_fetch_assoc($getArchives);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getArchives'])) {
  $totalRows_getArchives = $_GET['totalRows_getArchives'];
} else {
  $all_getArchives = mysql_query($query_getArchives);
  $totalRows_getArchives = mysql_num_rows($all_getArchives);
}
$totalPages_getArchives = ceil($totalRows_getArchives/$maxRows_getArchives)-1;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getRecent = "SELECT news.post_id, news.title FROM news ORDER BY news.post_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$getRecent = mysql_query($query_getRecent, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getRecent = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRecent);
$totalRows_getRecent = mysql_num_rows($getRecent);

$maxRows_getDisplay = 1;
$pageNum_getDisplay = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getDisplay'])) {
  $pageNum_getDisplay = $_GET['pageNum_getDisplay'];
}
$startRow_getDisplay = $pageNum_getDisplay * $maxRows_getDisplay;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getDisplay = "SELECT  news.post_id, news.title, news.pre,  DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC";
$query_limit_getDisplay = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getDisplay, $startRow_getDisplay, $maxRows_getDisplay);
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_limit_getDisplay, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getDisplay'])) {
  $totalRows_getDisplay = $_GET['totalRows_getDisplay'];
} else {
  $all_getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay);
  $totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($all_getDisplay);
}
$totalPages_getDisplay = ceil($totalRows_getDisplay/$maxRows_getDisplay)-1;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getPosts = "SELECT post_id, title, updated FROM news ORDER BY updated DESC";
$getPosts = mysql_query($query_getPosts, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPosts);
$totalRows_getPosts = mysql_num_rows($getPosts);

$queryString_getDisplay = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_getDisplay") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_getDisplay") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_getDisplay = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_getDisplay = sprintf("&totalRows_getDisplay=%d%s", $totalRows_getDisplay, $queryString_getDisplay);

$queryString_getArchives = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_getArchives") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_getArchives") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_getArchives = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_getArchives = sprintf("&totalRows_getArchives=%d%s", $totalRows_getArchives, $queryString_getArchives);



$var1_getDisplay2 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['archive'])) {
  $var1_getDisplay2 = $_GET['archive'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y'), news. AS formatted FROM news WHERE DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%Y-%%m') = %s ORDER BY news.updated DESC", GetSQLValueString($var1_getDisplay2, "text"));
} elseif (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
  $var2_getDisplay3 = $_GET['post_id'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted FROM news WHERE news.post_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($var2_getDisplay3, "int"));
} else {
  $query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT ".$pageNum_getDisplay.", 5";
}
$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
$totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($getDisplay);
?>
```

Comment: Well, have you considered that $row_getDisplay['post_id'] is not previously defined? (precisely as the error indicates :))

Comment: What does xdebug return when `var_dump($row_getDisplay);` ?

Comment: off topic: be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are now deprecated; it is recommended to stop using them and switch to the newer mysqli or PDO extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I editted the whole answer,

You don't select the post_id in your query:
Change the queries to this:

```
if (isset($_GET['archive'])) {
  $var1_getDisplay2 = $_GET['archive'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.post_id, news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y'), news. AS formatted FROM news WHERE DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%Y-%%m') = %s ORDER BY news.updated DESC", GetSQLValueString($var1_getDisplay2, "text"));
} elseif (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
  $var2_getDisplay3 = $_GET['post_id'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT news.post_id, news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted FROM news WHERE news.post_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($var2_getDisplay3, "int"));
} else {
  $query_getDisplay = "SELECT news.post_id, news.title, news.blog_entry, DATE_FORMAT(news.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC LIMIT ".$pageNum_getDisplay.", 5";
}
```

This wil also select the post_id for futher reference in your code, this will probably fix all your problems. (depending on how your database looks)

Added news.post_id for selection from the database. I think that this is the solution.

Comment: A line above your other code.. It has to be loaded before you excecute your a tag. (on line 263)

Comment: It seemed to give me an error in dreamweaver even before I got to save the document

Comment: Thank-you so much, I don't know why I didn't realise

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that the variable is not already set at this point.

But you can check if the variable is set and echo, if not don't.

Example:

```
echo (isset($row_getDisplay['post_id']) ? $row_getDisplay['post_id'] : '');
```

Here is how you would implement this into your code:

```
<h3><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['post_id']) ? $row_getDisplay['post_id'] : ''); ?>"><?php echo (isset($row_getDisplay['title']) ? $row_getDisplay['title'] : ''); ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: I've added another example in my answer.

Comment: It got rid of the error but the post_id comes up as nothing in the url, for example when I click on the title it goes to "http://localhost/blog_test/post.php?post_id="

Comment: That is because the variable is not set. We'll need to see more of the code to fix that issue.

Comment: I edited my original post to contain the code for the server behaviours